# Pandas, isin, column of lists

Tags: pandas

Trying to make a Boolean flag that reads TRUE if one value or another is within a list.  The below code is returning a FALSE for row 1 and I am not sure why, could someone help me understand why a FALSE is getting returned for the first row?

```
lists={'someList!':[[1,2,12,6,'ABC'],[1000,4,'z','a','bob']]}
dfLists = pd.DataFrame(lists)
dfLists['contains?']=dfLists['someList!'].isin([0,1])
```

Comment: Your code gives an error instead. Please provide a reproducible code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could someone help me understand why a FALSE is getting returned for the first row?

This isn't working because `.isin(values)` returns whether each element in the Series is contained in `values`.

You can use `{0, 1}` as a set and apply the truthiness of its intersection to each list:

```
>>> s = {0, 1}
>>> dfLists['someList!'].apply(lambda x: bool(s.intersection(x)))
0     True
1    False
```

This effectively does:

```
>>> s.intersection([1, 2, 12, 6, 'ABC'])
{1}
>>> s.intersection([1000, 4, 'z', 'a', 'bob'])
set()
```

The `bool` of the first result is `True`, because it is non-empty.

Answer (score 0):

Using Dataframe constructor flatten you `list` column, then using `isin`

```
pd.DataFrame(dfLists['someList!'].tolist()).isin([1,2]).any(1)
Out[39]: 
0     True
1    False
dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the dataframe a list of lists. It's comparing integers to lists, so it's not finding a match.

Define your columns distinctly, like this, and isin should work.

```
lists={'someList!':[1,2,12,6,'ABC'], 'someList2':[1000,4,'z','a','bob']}
```