# Pandas matching column isin another (list) column (broadcasting `.isin`)

Tags: pandas, broadcast, isin

In a workflow matching up a spec against some allowed values, I wish to find which rows (index) are matching a spec.

This is different from [Pandas, isin, column of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53285716/pandas-isin-column-of-lists), as I an not matching each row against a (static) list.

I can do it with `.explode` and `.groupby` or with `.apply`, but the first seems *very* complicated and the second has performance issues. There must be a better way, but which? I can't make `.isin` broadcast, which otherwise would seem like the best solution.

(Example code also at https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1d8v6n99NPBaSufOsaWe3eRRrMgoSG_rr?usp=sharing)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(data = {
    'name': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    'lst': [[0,2,4], [1,2], []],
    'spec': [2,4,0]
})
expect = pd.DataFrame(data= {
    'name': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    'match_spec': [True, False, False] 
})

def check(f):
  try:
    got = f()
    result = (expect['match_spec'] == got)
    ok = result.all()
    if ok:
      print(f'OK {f}')
    else:
      print(f'FAIL {f}\n{got}')
  except Exception as ex:
    print(f'ERROR {f}\n{ex}')

def naive_broadcast(): return df.spec in df.lst
check(naive_broadcast)

def result_apply(): return df.apply(lambda x: x.spec in x.lst, axis=1)
check(result_apply)

def naive_isin(): return df.spec.isin(df.lst)
check(naive_isin)

def vectorization(): np.vectorize(df.spec.isin)(df.lst.values)
check(vectorization)

# Another ugly way, exploding and grouping
def explode_groupby():
  exp = df.explode('lst')
  return (exp.assign(m = (exp['lst'].eq(exp['spec'])))
    .groupby('name')
    .agg(match_spec=('m', max))
    .reset_index()['match_spec'])
check(explode_groupby)
```

The above code produces:

```
ERROR <function naive_broadcast at 0x7fe0a4f6c9d0>
unhashable type: 'Series'
OK <function result_apply at 0x7fe0a4f6ca60>
FAIL <function naive_isin at 0x7fe0a4f6c310>
0    False
1    False
2    False
Name: spec, dtype: bool
ERROR <function vectorization at 0x7fe0a4f6c940>
setting an array element with a sequence.
OK <function explode_groupby at 0x7fe0a4f6ce50>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are concerned about performance here's something new

```
pd.DataFrame([*df['lst']]).eq(df['spec'], axis=0).any(axis=1)
```

Result

```
0     True
1    False
2    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: Interesting approach. I am not convinced about the performance though:
```
%timeit result_apply()
518 µs ± 9.48 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

def explode_eq(): return pd.DataFrame([*df['lst']]).eq(df['spec'], axis=0).any(axis=1)
%timeit explode_eq()
746 µs ± 21.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: @HelgeJensen Try a dataframe of bigger size for e.g. 100K rows. this solution will outperform others.

Comment: While you are right that your appoach scales nicely with len(df) it does not scale very well with len(np.unique(np.concatenate(df['lst']))).

I found a way to "vectorize in", see my own answer -- It was embarassingly simple :)

Answer (score 0):

After some experiments, I found a way to do vectorization "right"™ :)

```
def vectorize_in(): 
  def isin(spec, list):
    return spec in list
  vec_in = np.vectorize(isin)
  return vec_in(df['spec'], df['lst'])
check(vectorize_in)
OK <function vectorize_in at 0x7fe2de337550>
```

This approach scales very well, both in `len(df)`, `max(len(df.lst))` and `len(np.unique(np.concatenate(df['lst'])))`.

As seen by:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
rowcount = 10000

df = pd.DataFrame(data = {"spec": np.arange(0,rowcount)})
rand = np.random.default_rng(seed=42)
lst_mean = len(df)/2
lst_ln = 100
def mklist(x): 
  start = int(np.abs(rand.normal()*lst_mean))
  l = int(np.abs(rand.normal()*lst_ln))
  return np.arange(start-int(l/2), start+l)
df['lst']=df.apply(mklist, axis=1)

def explode_eq(): pd.DataFrame([*df['lst']]).eq(df['spec'], axis=0).any(axis=1)

%timeit result_apply()
234 ms ± 4.08 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit explode_eq()
1.16 s ± 222 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit vectorize_in()
32.4 ms ± 743 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```